# react-native 'Stylesheet' not exposing css in Browser DOM - react native for web server side rendering

Tags: react-native, server-side-rendering, react-native-web

The problem I am facing is when Server side rendering react-native for web. All css style class for DOM elements show up in CSS inspect console, but when I try to find the source code in dom i see an empty

I am working on react-native for web, all my css style code is written with Stylesheet.create() and have no problem with styles in my Android app & web builds. For web build i am using webpack.

I tried using
`const { getStyleElement } = AppRegistry.getApplication(appName); const css = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(getStyleElement());`

I am getting only partial css not the complete css styles
[(Empty style Tag)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQdTf.png).
I am expecting to capture complete CSS syle classes that are currently rendered in browser

[css class in DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWBLU.png)